# Can I extend the cheat screen time in NFL Blitz for the N64?

Tags: nfl-blitz

Right before you enter the stadium to play the game, there is a short period to enter (more like mash) in cheats to be applied to the football game...  Is there anyway to extend that short period to enter more cheats?

I am only able to get 3 to 4 cheats in, but I could enter a lot more if I can extend it...

[image]

Comment: Are you doing this on a standard n64? or a ROM?

Comment: Standard n64.  Not using a GameShark

Comment: I wouldn't think so then, unless theres a developer mode cheat. AFAIK The load screen is actually loading all the materials and what not, if you cant beat the time it takes for that much to load then I believe you're out of luck, but I never had to throw in more than 4 cheats